# Solr merging hight i/o

Tags: merge, io, solr

We are using Solr with over 30 million records per core,merge factor of 2. When merging/optimizing , the iops increases drastically. Is there any way to regulate the merging rate without changing merge factor? Like asking solr to use lesser number of threads to do the operations.We can afford slow merging but not such high i/o rate.
Found [this](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Can-I-tell-Solr-to-merge-segments-more-slowly-on-an-I-O-starved-system-td1522657.html) , any additional information will be very helpful.
Thanks